# Officejs: Can an outlook action trigger the taskpane

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a two fold questions.

1. Do actions have click events? I have a simple action that looks like the following:
   [image: Addin]
   I want to run some typescript code if a user clicks on that Action, is that possible? Are there event handlers for those actions?
2. From that click can I open the taskpane that is part of my addin? I have tried using `Office.addin.showAsTaskpane()` but I am not having any luck having that trigger the taskpane. I have been following this issue on github but even so I have not successfully been able to open my taskpane any other way than clicking the ribbon button for toggling the taskpane.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3250)

I have tried moving the `Office.addin.ShowAsTaskpane()` around to several areas of my `commands.ts`. I have tried in the `onRready()` as well as before and after my `event.complete()` Full code for my `commands.ts` is below:

```
Office.onReady(() => {
  Office.addin.showAsTaskpane().then();
});

/**
 * Shows a notification when the add-in command is executed.
 * @param event
 */
function action(event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) {
  const message: Office.NotificationMessageDetails = {
    type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
    message: "Performed action. - Click",
    icon: "Icon.80x80",
    persistent: true,
  };
  // Show a notification message
  Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);

  // Be sure to indicate when the add-in command function is complete
  event.completed();
  Office.addin.showAsTaskpane().then();
}

function getGlobal() {
  return typeof self !== "undefined"
    ? self
    : typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? window
    : typeof global !== "undefined"
    ? global
    : undefined;
}

const g = getGlobal() as any;

// The add-in command functions need to be available in global scope
g.action = action;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are looking for is an InsightMessage type of notification.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessageaction?view=outlook-js-preview